# angular-vb.net : How to pass angular variable to code behind

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, vb.net

Here is my `controller.js` code. I have a `uid` in `js` file.

I want to access this code from vb code behind.

```
    $scope.GetID = function (uGuid) {
        $scope.Outlets = JSON.parse(Outlets);           
        $scope.uid = uGuid;
        debugger;
        alert($scope.uid);
    }
```

I want to store uid as string in a button click.

```
 Dim aID As String = uid
```

Comment: you need to use $http post service... [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Is there any possibilities to store  $scope.uid as a session variable and use the session in code behind?

Comment: yes that is the way but wer you need this?

Comment: <tr data-ng-repeat="outlet in Outlets">                                                                        <td> <button data-ng-model="outlet.uGuid" data-ng-click="GetID(outlet.uGuid)">{{outlet.PartnerName}}</button>
</td>
</tr> This button click generate the uid. I want to pass the uid as a parameter in another function.I mean the button  shows the outlet names. When the button click i want to display the details of the outlet based on the uid.

Answer (score 0):

the better way is you generate UID in vb code and in VB code convert to string.
 or when you pass variable to angular function convert them in angular function "toString(uGuid)" and again send variable to backend code "vb

Comment: UID is a string value. so no need to string conversion. Actually i don't know how to  send variable from angular to backend code

Comment: <tr data-ng-repeat="outlet in Outlets"> <td> <button data-ng-model="outlet.uGuid" data-ng-click="GetID(outlet.uGuid)">{{outlet.PartnerName}}</‌​button> </td> </tr> How can i get the outlet.uGuid in my vb code?

Comment: first you must in Outlets list you have outlet.uGuid then  when  user click on button outlet.uGuid pass to angular controller then controller get this then from controller send to service and service send for vb code